# Summation of a sequence that is described by an nth term formula

Tags: sequences-and-series, summation

I have the following sequence: 2,10,26,50,82… I’ve concluded that the nth term of this sequence is given by: $4n^2 - 4n + 2$. How would I go about finding the sum of the first n terms?

$$\sum_{k=1}^n (4k^2-4k+2)$$

If I start by creating this sequence: 2, 2+10, 2+10+26, 2+10+26+50, 2+10+26+50+82… which is: 2,12,38,88,170… I would be able to find the nth term for this sequence and therefore have the formula for the summation of $n=1$ to $n$. However I’m unable to find the nth term formula for this sequence.

Comment: So you are saying e.g. $2,10,26,50,82,42,42,42,42,42,42,\dots$ is not a sequence?

Comment: very helpful...

Comment: There are formulas you can look up for sum of first n squares, etc that you can apply.

Comment: The sequence I’ve produced here is part of a much larger problem I’m trying to solve. It’s not an arbitrary sequence it’s definitely described by the formula I’ve wrote.

Comment: Blue5000--- did you try looking up th3e power sum formulas as not3d in comment?

Comment: Welcome to MSE. For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Comment: Presumably you know how to sum the sequence with terms given by $4n-2$. There is a formula for summing square numbers; just look up square pyramidal numbers. Then you can combine those results.

Comment: I think the Summand should be $4k^2-4k+2$

Comment: The sum is a cubic polynomial in $n$. Evaluate it at 4 points and interpolate.

Comment: Do you know the relevant results [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Faulhaber%27s_formula#Examples)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$\sum_{k=1}^n (4k^2-4k+2) = 2[(2+8+...2n^2)-(2+4+...2n)+n$$

$$= 2 \left[\frac{2n(n+1)(2n+1)}{6}-\frac{2n(n+1)}{2}+n\right]$$

$$= 2 \left[\frac{n(n+1)(2n+1)}{3}-n(n+1)+n\right]$$

$$= 2 \left[\frac{n(n+1)(2n-2)}{3}+n\right]$$

$$= 2 \left[n\left(\frac{2n^2-2}{3}\right)+n\right]$$

$$= 2 \left[n\left(\frac{2n^2+1}{3}\right)\right]$$

$$= \frac{2}{3} n(2n^2+1)$$

Comment: Thanks for the answer.

Answer (score 1):

$$\begin{align}\sum_{k=1}^n (4k^2-4k+2)&=\sum_{k=1}^n\left((2k-1)^2+1\right)\\
&=n+\sum_{j=1}^{2n}j^2-\sum_{i=1}^n(2i)^2\\
&=n+\frac{2n(2n+1)(4n+1)}6-4\frac{n(n+1)(2n+1)}6\\
&=n+\frac{n(2n+1)}3\left((4n+1)-2(n+1)\right)\\
&=\frac n3\left(3+4n^2-1\right)\\
&=\frac{2n\left(2n^2+1\right)}3.
\end{align}$$

Comment: Thanks for the answer.

Comment: Can the today-downvoter please explain how they believe I could improve my answer? (But this looks more like serial downvoting - 9 in two days - which will then be automatically reversed.)